# Iterating through pandas dataframe and appending to a list

Tags: list, pandas, loops, dataframe, append

I have a pandas dataframe df

```
    Date          SKU     Balance
0   1/1/2017        X1       8
1   2/1/2017        X2      45
2   3/1/2017        X1      47
3   4/1/2017        X2      16
4   5/1/2017        X1      14
5   6/1/2017        X2      67
6   7/1/2017        X2       9
8   8/1/2017        X1      66
9   9/1/2017        X1     158
```

I wanna break it and append it to a list so that each item in the list is the collection of 4 days of the data frame

For Example

List[1]

```
    Date          SKU     Balance
0   1/1/2017        X1       8
1   2/1/2017        X2      45
2   3/1/2017        X1      47
3   4/1/2017        X2      16
```

List[2]

```
     Date          SKU     Balance
0   2/1/2017        X2      45
1   3/1/2017        X1      47
2   4/1/2017        X2      16
3   5/1/2017        X1      14
```

At the moment I can only achieve by appending one day for each list by this below code

```
dr = pd.date_range('20170101','20170109')

list=[]
for d in dr:
   list.append(df.loc[df.Date.isin([d])])
```

As mentioned above,How can I append 4 days from the 1st day in one list and loop it to the 2nd day , append another 4 days of rows and so on.

Highly appreciate your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `reindex` and `np.r_` with list comprehension:

```
l = [df.reindex(np.r_[i:i+4]) for i in range(len(df))]
```

Comment: @Wen Thank you.  High praise coming from you.

Comment: Thanks Scott, Awesome

Comment: @AhamedMoosa Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can try with `np.roll`

```
l=[]
a=df.index.values
for x in a:
    l.append(df.loc[a[:4]])
    a=np.roll(a,-1)
```

Comment: Thanks wen , appreciate it ,I will take @Scott's answer . Hope you dont mind

Comment: @AhamedMoosa sure ~ If I were you , I will accept his answer as well :-)

Comment: :) Thanks buddy

Answer (score 0):

Slice in a list comprehension.

```
ls = [df.loc[i:i+3] for i in range(len(df))]
```

Comment: @ScottBoston, I did test this first. Can you be more specific?

Comment: ls[0] is correct 0:3, but ls[1] should be 1:4 not 4:8.

Comment: I guess I misread the question. This makes chunks, not a sliding window with overlap.

Comment: I removed the step from the range. It's now a sliding window, but it keeps the original index. This may or may not be what we want.